# How to do bitwise-lexicographic comparison

Tags: gcc, compare, bitwise-operators, lexicographic

The `gcc` compiler is interpreting `char` datatype as integer number, and it make sense... There are a compare function to **compare  it as bit strings**?

```
  char a='0';  
  char b= 0b11111111;
  if (a<b) {/* never goes here! */}
  if (bitStringCompare(a,b)) {/* this kind of "native" function exists? */}
```

A better way for my real-life problem is to declare `a` and `b`  with other datatype, that **is really a bit string**, for example (supposing) [`ASN1TDynBitStr`](https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/acv73/CCppHTML/ch04s01s03.html), but I not see the bitwise-lexicographic comparison for it.

---

### NOTES

The variable length bit-string lexicographic order is:
   `0` < `00` < `01` < `1` < `10` < `11`
where all items are bit strings (like `0b10` but with 0!=00), they are not ASCII strings. 
For mathematicians, using the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Monoid_of_words), each string is a word of an alphabet with 2 letters.

The `std::lexicographical_compare` not seems the solution because is not bitwise-oriented.

Important: I need good performance, so it is not valid (for my application) to transform bits into ASCII `0`s and `1`s. I need fast and bitwise-lexicographic-comparison.

---

Suggestion (imagining optimal solution): when dividing a **big bit string** into *n* chunks (e.g. with more tham 32 bits and less tham 1024 bits), scanning with *i*=0 to *n*-1... Perhaps the faster approach is to use chunk-at-a-time (e.g. chunck `x_i` of 32 bits) fast function to check `a_i==b_i`, them (when `a_i!=b_i`) use bit-at-a-time function to return `a_i<b_i`.

The bit string lexicographical comparison `a_i==b_i`  is possible for numerical (unsigned) datatypes when concatenating a bit `1`: for example to compare `0000==0` we can use `0b10000`==`ob10`.

Comment: From what I understand you're trying to do `is_less_than(to_string_base2(integer_a), to_string_base2(integer_b))` but efficiently, without the to-string conversions? Am I correct? If so, how do you ever get strings like `00` or `01`? Number to string conversion functions typically do not write out leading zeros?

Comment: Thanks @PSkocik, see my NOTES: "... they are not ASCII strings" ... "I need good performance ... I need fast and bitwise-lexicographic-comparison".

Comment: OK, I understand now: you the ASN1TDynBitStr type has a bit count so you know how many leading zerous should be in the stringified form. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PSkocik your question "without the to-string conversions?" is perhaps another way to express my question, "function exists?"  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest when you overlay the bits over an unsigned type (e.g., `unsigned char` rather than `char`). If the type can store `W` bits (8 in case of `char`), then you can address `nth` bit with

```
nth_bit(array,nth) array[nth/W]&(1ull<<(nth%W))
```

The easiest way to do your lexicographical bit-compare would then be to
start at the left and go over the bits, left-to-right [lexicographically comparing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/) them as if you went over characters in a string.

This approach could be sped up by comparing several bits at a time, but then you'd have to watch for how things aligned.

Comment: Yes, for **big bit sttrings** we need what you commented, *"This approach could be sped up by comparing several bits at a time"*... There is a function in C language to compare lexicographically `unsigned char`?

Comment: Absolutely. Hence the part about comparing several bits at a time. For large bit strings you'll get the best perf if you manage to compare lost of aligned word-sized chunks, but for small ones that might be misaligned, the bit version should be quicker and smaller. C only has strcmp, which only works on real strings, but the algorithm is trivial.

Comment: @PeterKrauss No. There isn't. It's trivial to adapt the C++ template but you could then still only use it if things are aligned. You could be comparing a 10 bit string with a 9 bit string. A lexicographical compare on unsigned chars would be of no use in that situation.

Comment: Hum... There are no modern CPU that help the implementation of something like  `bitstr_cmp`?  (are you sure about that?) Yes need aligned word-sized chunks, but need an internal fast function to compare in one step the chunk.

Comment: The bit-at-a-time version should have the smallest code-size footprint and could be fast enough.  For a fast version I'd look if things are aligned well enough and then do word-at-time or char at a time comparison and if they weren't I'd still compare several bits at a time by shifting from the next char/word. There might be faster approaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot PSkocik (!).  I will wait some weeks or months (conform pageviews) before to *click accept* in this answer, only to confirm that nobody see a kind of `bitstr_cmp` function. The "faster approaches" perhaps use chunk-at-a-time checking  if chuncks are identical (`a_i==b_i`), them use bit-at-a-time to check `a_i<b_i`.  The bit string check `00!=0` is possible by numerical comparizon, concatenating a bit `1`, `100!=10` in unsigned number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Wiki, please edit (!) and complement the answer.

---

This fragment shows that is possible to optimize:

1. by benchmark elect the chunk-length (something as 8, 16 or 32 bits), for faster bitwise comparison.
2. use bitwise comparison only once, all other are chunk equivalence.

Suppose that the best performance in the [@PSkocik bitwise comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56514214/287948)  is 8 bits (char) per chunck, and suppose that we are feeding data by long integers,

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdint.h>

  union Data {
    uint64_t i;  // unsigned long long
    char str[8]; // 8bits*8=64bits
  };

  int main( ) {
    int kmax = 6;
    union Data x[6] = {
      [0].i=0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010,
      [1].i=0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
      [2].i=0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101, //
      [3].i=0b0000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000011,
      [4].i=0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110,
      [5].i=0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111
    };
    printf( "\nComparing all with x[2], %zu bytes/item\n", sizeof(x[2]));
    for (int k=0; k<kmax; k++) {
      printf( "\nx[%d]: i=%ju\n\t", k, x[k].i);
      for (int j=7;j>=0;j--) {
        printf( " %d(%s)", j, (x[k].str[j]==x[2].str[j])? "=": "≠" );
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

Output:

```
Comparing all with x[2], 8 bytes/item

x[0]: i=2
     7(=) 6(=) 5(=) 4(=) 3(=) 2(=) 1(=) 0(≠)
x[1]: i=9223372036854775808
     7(≠) 6(=) 5(=) 4(=) 3(=) 2(=) 1(=) 0(≠)
x[2]: i=5
     7(=) 6(=) 5(=) 4(=) 3(=) 2(=) 1(=) 0(=)
x[3]: i=1073741827
     7(=) 6(=) 5(=) 4(=) 3(≠) 2(=) 1(=) 0(≠)
x[4]: i=6
     7(=) 6(=) 5(=) 4(=) 3(=) 2(=) 1(=) 0(≠)
x[5]: i=7
     7(=) 6(=) 5(=) 4(=) 3(=) 2(=) 1(=) 0(≠)
```